# What is the linux command that gives the paths to libraries for linking during c++ compilation?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I remember seeing some command that works like this:

```bash
g++ main.cpp `some_forgotten_command --some_forgotten_options some_library`
```

When the command is run, it will substitute the part enclosed by `` with `-I/path/to/some_library/include` and `-L/path/to/some_library/lib/` (or something similar, I don't remember exactly). However I could not remember what `some_forgotten_command` is.

Comment: Options normally go before file name. Hmm, unless its something very old or very new, g++ doesn't have something like this, afaik. `-L` provides path to a folder, while library's file is given by `-lsome_library`. what it could be some script that searches for files or content of installed package

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `-l` before the filename has no effect.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat wait, what? `-l<filename-without-lib-prefix>` is standard way to submit  library file name for gcc or G++.Are we even talking about same toolchain?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The order of `-l` matters with respect to other `-l` and with respect to `.o` (and probably `.cpp` too). `-l` only fixes undefined references in objects/libs to the left of it (at least on the LD linker, clang's LLD linker is order-independent).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `pkgconf` or `pkg-config` (those are two different implementations that do mostly the same thing).

`pkgconf --libs LibraryName` gives linker flags, and `pkgconf --cflags LibraryName` gives compiler flags.

You can use both `--libs` and `--cflags` in the same command (in your specific example, since you do compilation and linking together in a single command, you should use both).

And `pkgconf --list-all` prints a list of all installed library names.

Comment: Should be added that it works only on platforms where pkgconf or pkg-conf supported natively (e.g. it's not on Windows) and only for libraries which are build\configured with its use. There are at least three or four analogs of that tool, vcpkg is one , for example. The fact that there are so many options explains why we need tools like autoconf or CMake.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie *"only for libraries which [support it]"* Most serious libraries do. *"three or four analogs"* Not really, pkg-config is the build-system-agnostic standard. Vcpkg is a package manager, it doesn't help with the flags. Autotools only helps if you adopt it as a build system, I think? And while CMake does have some kind of pkg-config-like mode to get the flags without using it as a build system, it's fairly obscure.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `pkg-config`/`pkgconf` does work on Windows via MSYS2, at least for MinGW. I think it even has a flag for MSVC-styled output, but I never tried it.

Comment: Yeah, with vc\vcpkg one have to rely on checking if certain packages are installed and they would have predetermined locations. CMake on Widnows does that in obscure way. depends on use case. Let's say, a big enterprise network and there are libraries avallable which have metdate neither on Windows or linux-like systems. Because they aren't installed "from Internet" . In a way being dependant on it is similar to being dependant on apt or yum instead of dpkg - works most of the time except when you really serious about it. Even changes in pkg-config/pkgconf name and flags is annoying.